# I can not match the width of my website with mobiles screen

Tags: width

I have a website which I used the meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"  in it . but the width of that is not match  with the width of mobile devices (just mobiles ) . what should i do to match it with the mobiles screen ?

Comment: which i used ( <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> ) in it *

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a style that sets the width dependent on the screen:

```
body {
    width: auto;
}
```

If you're designing for only mobile devices the W3 site has good tutorials: [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_mobile.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3pro.css">
<body>

<!-- Content here -->

</body>
</html>
```